# Is it possible to establish communication between multiple AMQP brokers

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic, amqp

Is it possible to publish/consume messages to ActiveMQ using RabbitMQ libraries and vice versa? Both are AMQP brokers, So I want to check if this is possible or not.

I am asking this question as I have a usecase to migrate our current broker and I dont want my customer to do any changes while consuming messages. This can be any AMQP broker to any other AMQP broker communication

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ (both the 5.x and Artemis brokers) support AMQP 1.0. Therefore, any client which communicates over the AMQP 1.0 protocol can interact with the broker regardless of what other brokers that client may be working with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can the client consume from some ActiveMQ using rabbitMQ library?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the RabbitMQ client library, but if it uses AMQP 1.0 exclusively to communicate with the broker then it should work.